# What is a "Try Get Pawn Owner" in Unreal Engine 4?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I am following a FPS Video Tutorial from DevSquad https://youtu.be/ftLBejDtlqc

On the 3:53 mark of the video, I noticed that there is a node called "Try Get Pawn Owner". Does anyone know what this does? I checked the Unreal Engine Documentation about it but it does not explain anything.

Answer (score 3):

It is a function exclusively available in Anim Blueprints.

It returns the Owner of the Anim BP as Pawn.

Which means that if your SkeletalComponent's Owner is not a Pawn but a simple Actor, it will return `None`.

So if the SkeletalComponent is part of a Pawn or a subclass of a Pawn, it will work.

Comment: maybe is useful in the Blueprint, but any function in the BP is coded in the engine, so it's not "exclusive" of BP. This is the C++ implementation: `virtual APawn* TryGetPawnOwner() const;`.

Comment: no one codes animations in cpp

Answer (score 2):

To clarify what Raildex said, the node "TryGetPawnOwner" is literally saying, get the owner of this AnimBP (the owner being the actor that your skeletal mesh is contained within) and see if it is a Pawn. If it is a pawn, then it will return true. If it is not a pawn, then it will fail.

So if you drag a skeletal mesh into the world and set it to use the AnimBP, then TryGetPawnOwner will always fail because a skeletal mesh is not a pawn. If instead, you create a new Blueprint of class Pawn or Character (which is a type of pawn) and then add your skeletal mesh to that pawn and set it to use the AnimBP, then it will return true.
So instead of using the TryGetPawnOwner node which Epic incorrectly uses in every example, you could instead use the "GetOwningActor" node which will always return true because every object you place in the world derives from the Actor base class.

[image]